# Easy way to assign a word to a string using a scanner?

Tags: java

I have a problem. If I assign a word to a string directly (by doing s="pass"), the code works the way I want. But if I try to assign it use a scanner, it seems to just skip over the if statement. I'm obviously new to java, could someone please try to help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s;
    s=scan.next();

    if(s=="pass"){
        System.out.println("CORRECT");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("INCORRECT");
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported the Scanner properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String.equals()` method compares the contents of the string, whereas the `==` operator checks to see whether or not the objects are equal.

Change

```
if(s=="pass"){
        System.out.println("CORRECT");
    }
```

to

```
if(s.equals("pass")){
        System.out.println("CORRECT");
    }
```

More information: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

Answer (score 2):

replace `(s=="pass")` with `s.equals("pass")` [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Here `==` will compare the references not the content.

To compare the content you need to use

```
.equals()    //If case is important

.equalsIgnorecase()  //If case is not important
```

But as your question says way to assign string is you can use `=` operator